# There was an error deserializing the object of type .... The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

Iam get an intemittant error when posting to a WCF webservice

```
The exception message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type. The maximum   
string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data.
```

I have tried various different suggestions but with no luck

Can anyone see what iam missing or doing incorrectly ?

thanks

The config file on the client is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0"    sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup><system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IAWSSESService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="320" maxStringContentLength="81920" maxArrayLength="163840"
                    maxBytesPerRead="40960" maxNameTableCharCount="163840" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:20930/AWSSESService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IAWSSESService"
            contract="AwsWebService.IAWSSESService" name="WSHttpBinding_IAWSSESService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The config file for the web service is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="CG.Core.EmailService.AWSSESService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="CG.Core.EmailService.IAWSSESService" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpDefaultConfig"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpDefaultConfig">
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"     multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<!--
     -->
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: are you sure the error message is 8192 and not 81920?

Comment: What else have you tried?  @JustinWilliams question is good.

Comment: Both server and client would need to have the same readerQuota settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by copying the wshttpbinding from the client and pasting it into the web config file